# How to spark-submit a Spark Streaming application with spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 dependency?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am tring to run the spark streaming example :
[Directkafkawordcount.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala)

To create jar I am using "build.sbt" with plugin:

```
     name := "Kafka Direct"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"  exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog")
)
resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Maven Central" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
)



 mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          =>     MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      =>     MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties"                                  =>     MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") =>     MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                    =>     MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                   =>     MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "pom.properties" =>  MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
  oldStrategy(x)
}
```

"sbt package" is successful but when I want to submit with from target/scala-2.11/classes directory:
"spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount  --master local[2] /home/hadoop/DirectKafkaProject/target/scala-2.11/kafka-direct_2.11-1.0.jar localhost:9092 xyz123"

it give me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)

I already set SPARK_CLASSPATH and SPARK_LOCAL_IP. I already try with -jars option but it is asking for another .jar file and it keep asking  for other .jar files. I had done every thing what every this site suggested but I am no able to solve my problem.
Scala version: 2.11.6
spark version: 2.1.0
kafka version: 2.11-0.10.2.0 .

Please  help me . Thanks.

Comment: You need to add Kafka jar, Kafa utils, metrics core jar to spark classpath.

Comment: My spark classpath is set with spark's jars and kafka jar's.

Comment: I try with this "spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount  --jars  /home/hadoop/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.1.0.jar,/home/hadoop/jars/kafka-clients-0.10.2.0.jar,/home/hadoop/jars/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar,/home/hadoop/jars/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar --master local[2] /home/hadoop/DirectKafkaProject/target/scala-2.11/kafka-direct_2.11-1.0.jar localhost:9092 MyTest1" . But now it is showing "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker
". So, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: but last command showing me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker" this exception. thanks .

Comment: Are you sure that kafka on your machine is up and running? and once try to add spark-kafka-streaming jar to both spark and kafka classpath and try again.

Comment: My kafka-console-producer and consumer both are working.But this program not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `sbt assembly` and `spark-submit`

`sbt assembly` assembles all the dependencies in one single jar file and given you use the external library for Kafka that's what I'd recommend.

And you've got the definition for [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin in `build.sbt` already that suggests it's the way to go.

---

Executing assembled Spark application is using `spark-submit` command-line application as follows:

```
bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount \
  --master local[2] \
  target/scala-2.11/StreamKafkaPr‌​og-assembly-1.0.jar localhost:9092 rat123
```

Comment: I was thinking like you before but It is not working for me.That is why with spark-submit command I used --jars option . But it is not working is here any problem with version missmatch or something ?

Comment: Thanks Jacek Laskowaki! you are right. once I done sbt assembly my problem solved. and in build.sbt file I make a little change:                                libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided" resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Maven Central" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
    "Kafka Central" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles on this post (like I did). The answer by Jacek is very much correct. For me it still was not working, because the merging strategy is crucial (and I used some examples from the internet).
The most simplest form (assuming you only have `spark` and `spark-sql-kafka` etc.) that works for me is

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```